# How to display XMLRPC client's array values in a third party website , after got response from the XMLRPC server?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, xml-rpc, xmlrpcclient

I've created a XMLRPC webservice using Codeigniter. I've got response from XMLRPC Server correctly. But I want to list the response values in a third party website. I get response as array values. I've added the XMLRPC client result below,

sample url: http://music-shop.saas.com/xmlrpc_client/listGeneres  - I get XMLRPC response in this page (This is localhost url only).

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [parent_id] => 0
            [cart_id] => 2
            [name] => Blues
            [slug] => blues
            [route_id] => 48
            [description] => 
            [excerpt] => 
            [sequence] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [parent_id] => 0
            [cart_id] => 2
            [name] => Country
            [slug] => country
            [route_id] => 49
            [description] => 
            [excerpt] => 
            [sequence] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [parent_id] => 0
            [cart_id] => 2
            [name] => Jazz
            [slug] => jazz
            [route_id] => 50
            [description] => 
            [excerpt] => 
            [sequence] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [parent_id] => 0
            [cart_id] => 2
            [name] => Hip hop
            [slug] => hip-hop
            [route_id] => 51
            [description] => 
            [excerpt] => 
            [sequence] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [parent_id] => 0
            [cart_id] => 2
            [name] => Audio CDs
            [slug] => audio-cds
            [route_id] => 52
            [description] => 
            [excerpt] => 
            [sequence] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [parent_id] => 0
            [cart_id] => 2
            [name] => Clothes
            [slug] => clothes
            [route_id] => 53
            [description] => 
            [excerpt] => 
            [sequence] => 0
        )

)
```

How to get this array values from the above URL in a third party website ? I want to scrap the array values to a new site.

Thanks in advance.